# Creating a TreeGraph?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, graph, treeview

I am in the process of trying to design a graph.  I am not sure the correct term for this type of graph.  It is similar to a tree view but instead is nested within the graph.

It looks something like this.

[image: This is the type of graph I am talking about.]

Where each color is a different hierarchy  and the next level breaks down from that.

The information will be dynamically loaded from the server which runs a stored procedure that is used for a tree view currently.
Does anyone know a good way to create this or maybe a open graph plugin for this?  jQuery, asp.net, c# all work for me.

Comment: maybe you can try nested Repeaters if the number of leves is static.

Comment: Yes.  Number of levels is static but the number of items each row is dynamic.  Would repeaters still work in that sense?

Comment: Yes they do, I used two nested repeaters to show one (or many) surveys to a user, every survey had different amount of questions.

Comment: Quick thinking, maybe you can create <ul> lists dinamically using the repeaters and create some css code to display as wanted